# The Talkative Badge

Tags: discussion, badges

I was awarded the **[Talkative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731)** badge the other day. The badge could use a better label. Talkative sounds more like a *demerit* than anything else. What about **Articulate**, **Fluent**, **Eloquent**, **Persuasive**? There must be someone there that gets paid to come up with better names than I do... :O)

Comment: But it's very difficult to tell if your messages were any of those things; it's just a count.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please give your suggestions, otherwise you're just being **Talkative**.

Comment: No, I'm being a [commentator](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/31/commentator) and/or [pundit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit). My suggestion: leave the name, does it matter?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, you gave your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: How about **Loquacious** :)? Seriously, I don't see anything negative about the adjective "talkative". All it means is that one is "fond of talking".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I like **Loquacious**. Actually it was in my list of suggestions but i left it out. When i hear "talkative" i almost feel like apologizing... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bronze badge. That's the entry-level badge. Your names would be more appropriate for the silver or gold badge. Of course, there is no gold badge, and the silver badge is called "Outspoken".

If you're sensing a theme here of not-so-glowing-titles for the badges, it's because chat is not one of the central features of Stack Overflow and chatting is not necessarily something that we are trying to encourage.

You get much nicer sounding badges for asking questions, answering questions, and participating in moderation duties.

Comment: I don't like chatting either but SO often suggests to _"continue this discussion in chat"_ if the comments section gets over a certain size.

Comment: That actually means "please stop posting comments, there are too many already" :)

Comment: @HansPassant: agreed. Even the badge itself says so... :)